# Trying to use "file_get_contents" but it won't work for a specific website

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, user-agent

I'm trying to build a first small project just for the fun of it. So basically what I want to do is to get data (price of a product) from a different website, and as part of the process I'm trying to use "file_get_contents". On few sites that I have tested everything went fine, but for some reason there's one website that doesn't seem to work.

When I'm using the basic code:

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.ivory.co.il/catalog.php?id=14589');
echo $url;
```

It just constantly reloads the page.

Even when I'm trying to get the source code of the website, I get a huge code. Here's a part of it:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>X0ww.Y2B=function (){return typeof X0ww.E2B.C2B==='function'?X0ww.E2B.C2B.apply(X0ww.E2B,arguments):X0ww.E2B.C2B;};X0ww.a8=function(){var l4=function(b4,B4){var R4=B4&0xffff;var y4=B4-R4;return(y4*b4|0)+(R4*b4|0)|0;},s4=function(C8,E8,c8){var l8=0xcc9e2d51,n8=0x1b873593;var T4=c8;var O8=E8&~0x3;for(var z8=0;z8<O8;z8+=4){var k4=C8.charCodeAt(z8)&0xff|(C8.charCodeAt(z8+1)&0xff)<<8|(C8.charCodeAt(z8+2)&0xff)<<16|(C8.charCodeAt(z8+3)&0xff)<<24;k4=l4(k4,l8);k4=(k4&0x1ffff)<<15|k4>>>17;k4=l4(k4,n8);T4^=k4;T4=(T4&0x7ffff)<<13|T4>>>19;T4=T4*5+0xe6546b64|0;}k4=0;switch(E8%4){case 3:k4=(C8.charCodeAt(O8+2)&0xff)<<16;case 2:k4|=(C8.charCodeAt(O8+1)&0xff)<<8;case 1:k4|=C8.charCodeAt(O8)&0xff;k4=l4(k4,l8);k4=(k4&0x1ffff)<<15|k4>>>17;k4=l4(k4,n8);T4^=k4;}T4^=E8;T4^=T4>>>16;T4=l4(T4,0x85ebca6b);T4^=T4>>>13;T4=l4(T4,0xc2b2ae35);T4^=T4>>>16;return T4;};return{C4:s4};}();X0ww.b1U=function(){var q1U=2;while(q1U!==1){switch(q1U){case 2:return{x1U:function(m1U){var V1U=2;while(V1U!==14){switch(V1U){case 4:V1U=X1U===m1U.length?3:9;break;case 1:var e1U=0,X1U=0;V1U=5;break;case 9:G1U+=String.fromCharCode(E1U.charCodeAt(e1U)^m1U.charCodeAt(X1U));V1U=8;break;case 2:var G1U='',E1U=decodeURI("e%253#Z%0Cg%10%03%19%7Ccr%05%0E%14myg%10%03%19ihc%02%14%12ziz%08%04%03pr%00%22/?DC%00lq$ZI%5D%22%3E4dGD6.'OC%003q%20GH%5E%17:+AJS%7B%04%19_CH5)/%5ECX%0E.(_TK!+#L%0Cf%14%0A%13ij%004)4GT%0A&22@%06C%3C%3Cl%7Dhg%10%08%0Dmbu%03%1E%08lcx%14%09%19%7Fch%16%17ld%0CI#%3E'%5CCo'%3E(%5C%0CK=+.IDO%252%25%02gI#4%16l%60%04%01%1F%00%13gN%3E?$%06u%5E#%3E'E%1Dk6%18)FRX%3E7hiAi%3E52ZIFj%1F#%5EGF%07%09%1EkRX=u%02MPK=%0D%14pe%5E#7h%19%1Dg084GKO52'nJK%223%16IVO#u%0BIEX%3E6#LOK%177'%5BNz0+#Z%1Dg%22#+D%14%04%15%14%0BlII$6#FR%11%1C(%3EEJ%18%7F%03%0Bdn~%05%0B%7Dxbl%7F%0B%22Ne%5E#7%7DySC20%12AKO%7F%0A3AEA%052+M%1D%7B$2%25CrC%3C%3E%05@CI:%14$BCI%25u%17%5DOI:%0F/ECi9%3E%25C%08%1Bj%09#IJz=:?MT%11%03%3E'DvF0%22#Z%08x4:*xJK(%3E4%00RGx%7B%07KRC'%3E%1E%08eE?/4GJ%0Ayht%05DC%25r%7DzCK=%0D/LCE%7F%09#IJ%7C8?#G%0E%5E%3CrfiE%5E8-#p%06i%3E52ZIFqsu%1A%0BH8/o%13uI#26%5COD6u%02AE%5E84(ITSj%08%11kRF%7F%08%11kRFj%08.MJF%7F%0E%0F%60CF!%3E4%13uB%3E8-_G%5C4%1D*IUB%7F%08.GEA&:0M%60F0(.%13uA(+#%06bO%25%3E%25%5COE?%60%12lei%257h%7Cbi%12/*%13qg%017'QCX%7F%14%05p%1DX%3C4%25P%08x4:*xJK(%3E4%08a%18q%18)FRX%3E7%7DZKE2#hzCK=%0B*I_O#%7B%01%1A%06i%3E52ZIF%7Fjl%1F%14Z)q%07KRC'%3E%1EgD@482%02LY%3E56%02QO3%3C*%08@X0%3C+MH%5Eq(.IBO#%7B.AABq2(%5C%06Z#%3E%25AUC%3E5%7C%02AO%25%0F/ECP%3E5#g@L%22%3E2%02yZ9:(%5CIG%7B(*AEO%7B%0FlFIX%3C:*%02df%04%1E%19jo~%02q4MKE'%3Elf%0CG%3E5)%5BVK2%3ElAUz%3E2(%5CoD%01:2@%0CY%25:%25C%0C_??#NOD4?l%5ECD544%08%1B%17qy%04ZOK?
```

It seems like it is encrypted in a way. I also tried using cURL and User-Agent, but it still won't work.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: it looks like you put the source code to a $url var. First rename the $url to something else. Just to be sure that your script doesnt get blew up by another prt of your script.  and it can also be possible that the page has a redirect build in. So if your browser shows the source he gets also the redirect. Dump the stuff on the harddisk and try to look at the result by a normal editor. Then you knwo what you get.

Comment: You should check if the web-site as an api to get the information you need.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't encrypted. That website is likely using a JS framework to load data into a skeleton rather than rendering pages server side. If you want to programmatically get those pages you need to use something that can render javascript.

As you've discovered, neither `file_get_contents()` or `curl` are such tools. Something like this php wrapper for headless chrome may work for you.

https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php